# Cakephp naming convention contradiction?

Tags: php, cakephp, conventions

I don't understand the following. In the Book, they says:

> Multiple word controllers can be any ‘inflected’ form which equals the controller name so:
>
> ```
> /redApples
> /RedApples 
> /Red_apples 
> /red_apples
> ```
>
> will all resolve to the index of the RedApples controller. However, the convention is that your URLs are lowercase and underscored, therefore /red_apples/go_pick is the correct form to access the RedApplesController::go_pick action.

But if I write this on add.ctp view

```
echo $this->Html->link('Add Red Apples',
                    array('controller' => 'RedApples', 'action' => 'add'),
                    array('class' => 'button'));
```

it's create this html output:

```
www.site.com/RedApples/add
```

So, The correct way to access RedApplesController::add is /red_apples/add, but CakePHP html helper creates links like /RedApples/add? Which is the correct way to write my own links?

Thank you.

Comment: The inconsistency, it seems, is in the use of 'controller' for the key name in the array, since the value taken literally as a part of the URL. Use `array('controller' => 'red_apples'...)`. The value will be used in the URL and will map to the controller named `RedApples`.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins - the value is not taken literally as part of the URL - it's used to create the URL and can/will change depending on routes...etc.

Comment: You are right georgecummins. My mistake was to use "controller" => "RedApples" (as a tutorial), when I can use "red_apples" to force to the correct way of convention. Any way, I supposed that I have to use the controller name (is "RedApples"!) and not the underscored version of the name. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused as to what the issue is.

1. it says that you CAN use any form
2. you use a form other than the recommended
3. it displays the form you chose

What's the problem?  The fact that it gives you a convention (but says it will accept non-conventional as well) and you've decided against using the convention doesn't equate to a problem IMO.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the real question?

> Which is the correct way to write my own links?

The "correct" way is the way you copy/pasted from the book where it almost literally says "the correct way is..."

> However, the convention is that your URLs are lowercase and
>   underscored, **therefore /red_apples/go_pick is the correct form** to
>   access the RedApplesController::go_pick action.

If for some unknown reason you must use "RedApples" (a variable you can't change or something?) as your controller name in your link creation, you could wrap it in an inflector:

```
$myController = 'RedApples'; //unable to change to 'red_apples' for some reason
//...
'controller'=>Inflector::tableize($myController)
//...
```

Comment: I was not very clear about that I know that the correct way is the underscored version, but don't understand why if i use "controller" => "RedApples" (that is logic for me, because is the correct name of the controller), it's create a link out of convention. (/RedApples instead of automaticaly /red_apples). Really I didn't understand how the html helper works...so thank you for your answer.